# Looking for a CIS Bechmark Tool to run against Amazon Linux 2016.09

Tags: audit, amazon

I have been tasked with ensuring the CIS Bechmark on Amazon Linux 2016.09.

Does anyone know of an examination tool that will output the difference between the current and the benchmark?

Unfortunately I cannot use one of the existing marketplace AMI's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lynis](https://cisofy.com/lynis/) is the open source alternative which not only does CIS but few other compliance tests as well.

The ability to modify the code to generate custom reports is handy for large number of systems.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not free, one way of assessing systems against CIS benchmarks is to use [Temable Nessus](https://www.tenable.com/products/nessus-vulnerability-scanner)

Amongst other things, they have CIS audit files for Amazon Linux.